# How to test in cypress that one date is 6 months earlier than another

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I have an svg graph I'm testing and on the x axis it has dynamic dates, for the purpose of this example lets say earlyDate is 'Feb 22' and LaterDate is 'Aug 22'.

I'm able to get the values from each element in the graph and store them in variables but I'm at a loss as to how I check that the earlyDate is always 6months before the laterDate in cypress. So far this is what I have:

```
//To get the earlyDateValue
cy.get("laterDateSelector").invoke('text').as('val');
  cy.get('@val').then((val) => {
   let laterDate = val;
```

```
//Assertion, this is where I'm stuck
cy.get('earlyDateSelector').should('equal', 'Need this part to be equal: laterDate minus 6 months in the format MMM yy');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [dayjs](https://day.js.org/en/) package it's fairly easy.

The date strings you have will parse directly, then do subtraction on the `$M` properties.

```js
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

it('checks 6 months between dates', () => {
  
  cy.get("earlyDateSelector").invoke('text').then(earlyDate => {       // 'Feb 22'
    cy.get("laterDateSelector").invoke('text').should(laterDate => {     // 'Aug 22'

      const early = dayjs(`01 ${earlyDate}`)  // '01 Feb 22'
      const later = dayjs(`01 ${laterDate}`)  // '01 Aug 22'

      expect(later.$M - early.$M).to.eq(6)

      // or, better for difference across years

      expect(end.diff(start, 'M')).to.eq(6)

    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you! 

That seemed to do the trick, do you have any suggestions on how to make this work when the earlyDate & lateDate is across multiple years? trying that now but getting an error(see below). As an example say earlyDate is Aug 21 and lateDate is Aug 22. See below for error message I'm getting:



expected NaN to equal 12

Comment: Sorry I made an incorrect assumption about the parsing. For a string `Aug 22` the parse result is 22 Aug 2022 - I assumed it would give 01 Aug 2022.  That can be fixed by prefixing `01`.

Comment: Ignore above comment, issue I was having was due to the locators changing based on the graph! Works perfectly now, thank you so much!